# test condition of advance custom field is true in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm trying to test if a post has either of two conditions of a custom field. i'm using the plugin advanced custom types. i've created a field called visibility whereby the administrator can select whether a post of page is public or private. this will then display a custom message depending on whether the user is logged in and the condition of the field. However with my code below the condition is always returned as public even if the field is set to private on a post.

```
<?
$visibility = get_field('visibility');

if($visibility='public'){ 


get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); 


} else if ($visibility='private') { ?>

<p>You must be logged in to view this post</p>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Shorty, take a look at a difference between `=` and `==`.

You are assigning, and therefore your **first** condition is always true.

For comparing use always `==` or `===`, pay a great deal of attention to that.

Comment: ahh i don't know whats changed but that this no longer works. I used `==` and does not work. Maybe i didn't test properly before :(

Comment: My answer was pointing at your really big php coding mistake, and it was using assigning operator when comparing. And if you fixed your operator, there is nothing I can do. You are better off checking your return of `get_field('visibility')`